# using JOIN in sql to get data from another database in the same server using an id

Tags: sql

I have been trying to test this but have as of yet been unsuccessful. I am trying to get the different characters of a user using the user's id. The two different tables are simple the user only having an id and a name the id being a primary key the character table only having an id (Primary key) , characterName, and a user id. I have been trying to use W3schools but when I try to select the second table it throws up errors.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE searchUserCharacter
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @userId INT
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT Id,character
FROM tableUser.dbo.[user]
INNER JOIN tableUserCharacter.dbo.userCharacter
ON tableUser.dbo.[user].Id=tableUserCharacter.dbo.userCharacter.userId
    END
    GO
```

Comment: what error are you getting? also - I assume you want to include a where clause in there to limit it to your @userId

Comment: On character beside SELECT I get an invalid column name,
the tableuser.... beside INNER JOIN says invalid object name
and beside ON tableUserCharacter.dbo.user... says the multipart identifier could not be bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliases

```
SELECT myUsers.Id,myUserCharacters.character
FROM tableUser.dbo.[user] myUsers
INNER JOIN tableUserCharacter.dbo.userCharacter myUserCharacters
ON myUsers.Id=myUserCharacters.userId
```

Comment: On character by the SELECT I am still getting an error saying invalid column name.
the text beside INNER JOIN is also still saying invalid object name.

myUserCharacters.userId is also saying 
the multi-part identifier "myUserCharacters.userId" could not be bound

Comment: Fixed I think, oops in select list as well. Syntax works for me (Sql 2012) anyway

Answer (score 0):

Is this SQL Server? Check your table carefully and ensure the table and column names match exactly. Make sure the tables are indeed in the schema 'dbo'

If this is in SQL Server, go into management studio, right click a table and generate a select statement and run it. Make sure your table and column names above match what is in the select statement.

It seems the issue is around

```
tableUserCharacter.dbo.userCharacter
```

So on the same server, switch to the database **tableUserCharacter** and ensure that that tables exsits in the **dbo** schema.

Comment: I have what is writen running but how would I put a WHERE statment so it only selects characters that have the same userId as the id from the user table?

Comment: What was the problem? You'll need to repost the SQL that works before we can suggest further enhancements to it. If you're saying the existing SQL works, then it should already match based on your ON clause.